# Vim: Backwards range -- OK to swap

Tags: vim

I have a file with tons of SQL output from different queries -- includes headers from each query.

Ex.

```
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
billy   william         smith   472750  
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
steve   bubba           gump    472751
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
george  Gigi            Jones   989989
```

Leaving aside the fact that I could just turn off headers ...

Supposing I wanted to keep the first instance of the header and delete all other instances:

In vim:

```
:2,$/^userid/d
```

So -- starting at line 2, ending at last line -- delete all lines that start with userid. Seems logical -- I could use `:g` [ and it works ], but  I get this message if I try the range:

> Backwards range given, OK to swap (y/n)?

What am I missing?

Comment: Related: [How to avoid 'Backwards range given' warning when invoking search range?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10289/467)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:g` takes a range so I think the correct command to be using is `:2,$g/^userid/d`.

Not entirely sure whats happening without the `g` but it doesn't seem to being doing what you want when I test it.

Heres what the docs say about the error in any case (`:h 493`)

```
Reverse Range                       *E493*

A range should have the lower line number first.  If this is not the case, Vim
will ask you if it should swap the line numbers.
    Backwards range given, OK to swap ~
This is not done within the global command ":g".

You can use ":silent" before a command to avoid the question, the range will
always be swapped then.
```

Comment: I should have looked closer at the docs for `:g` ...missed that! Thanks, works perfectly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28225756/1427295 for an explanation of what `:2,$/^userid/d` actually does.