# What is actually happening with this malformed command?

Tags: vim

The problem in [Vim: Backwards range — OK to swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28224540/1427295) turned out to be a missing `g` in the command `:2,$/^userid/d`. However the command will still runs, converting this:

```
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
billy   william         smith   472750  
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
steve   bubba           gump    472751
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
george  Gigi            Jones   989989
```

To This:

```
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
steve   bubba           gump    472751
userid  firstname       surname cardnumber
george  Gigi            Jones   989989
```

Can anyone give an explanation of what the malformed command is actually doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking what does `lineSpecifier/pattern/` do. Your range expression is starting at `2 (line2)` ending with `$/userid/`.

If you do `:h :range` (Thanks @Ingo for finding it ), you can find:

> The "/" and "?" may be preceded with another address.  The search starts from there.

`lineSpecifier/pattern/` will search `/pattern/` from the `lineSpecifier` line. E.g. `$/userid/` will search `/userid/` from the end of line. Also `4/userid/` will search `/userid/` from line `4`, that is, after execution, the cursor is at `line 5`. So `$/userid/` will make cursor at line `1`, this could be tested by `:$/userid/`.

so your command is same as `2,1d`, that's why vim asked you the confirmation of backwards range. If you pressed `y`, it will remove the first two lines, and leave the output like that.

Comment: In the help, this can be found under `:help :range`: _The "/" and "?" may be preceded with another address.  The search starts from
there._

Comment: @IngoKarkat thanks. I do read the `:range`, but overlooked that part... edited answer accordingly.